# Can we change font style in Sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, font-size

I am creating a SharePoint site. I want to customize the content. I am able to change color and font-size But I don't find any ways to change font-style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have different font-style in SharePoint we can copy the text in the required font-style from another location and paste in SharePoint.

Comment: Yes,  set font-style like the demo in the post above. I tested in my local, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set font-style in SharePoint like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.menu-item-text{
     font-style:italic !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Where should we include this CSS?

Comment: You can include this style in SharePoint Master Page or a specific page where you want to apply the style using Script Editor Web Part

Comment: Can I create a page where when a user with access to the page will have a popup, the popup contains a few fields for the user to answer? When the popup is properly submitted, it will copy a folder in particular one drive to users one drive.

Comment: @MyaGwen It seems a new question ? It seems less related with original question..

Comment: Actual Question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/61477417/8963353

Comment: Let's focus on the original question in one thread, for another question, talk in another thread. And did the solution for this question work for you ?

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. It is working fine.